# Generic failure using sp_send_dbmail in SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql-server, sp-send-dbmail

I'm trying to use `sp_send_dbmail` to send the results of a query through a SQLAgent job in SQL Server 2014.  I believe I have my DBMail profile set up properly but when running this:

```
exec msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
@profile = 'TestProfile',
@recipients = 'testmail@gmail.com',
@subject = 'Test',
@query = 'SELECT id FROM TestTable',
@attach_query_result_as_file = 1,
@query_attachment_filename = 'TestValues.txt'
```

I get the following error message:

```
Failed to initialize sqlcmd library with error number -2147467259.
```

Googling this error message didn't turn up anything useful, likely due to the generic error number.  Anyone have some insight into this error message?

Comment: Is your instance set up for DBMail?  In SSMS right click on the instance at the top of the Object Explorer and choose Facets.  Change the Facet to Surface Area Configuration and make sure DatabaseMailEnabled = True.

Comment: Great point; DatabaseMailEnabled is True for my server though.  That doesn't seem to be the issue for me.  I'm continuing testing today and will post anything I find that seems to help.

Comment: Hmmm, just found that if I remove the `@query, @attach_query_result and @query_attachment_filename`, then replace them with just a simple `@body` message, it works fine.  As soon as I put `@query` back in, it fails.  I could see it being a permission issue through SqlAgent but I'm just trying to run the command from a Query window with my admin user at the moment.

Comment: Is your sqlagent user account set as sysadmin?

Comment: Not sysadmin but it has high-level permissions.  I found the issue though: despite my query window pointing at the correct DB, the script in my original post has no concept of database orientation; you need to tell it what context/db it should run against by either fully qualifying the table in the `@query` variable or specifying a `@execute_query_database` parameter. Either of the following fixes my issue:
`@query = 'select id from dbo.testDB.TestTable` or `@execute_query_database = 'testDB'`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found that despite both my query window (for testing) and SqlAgent job were pointing at my desired DB, sp_send_dbmail doesn't seem to have any database context.  My original post was failing because SQL didn't know where to run `SELECT * FROM TestTable`.  The fix is to provide sp_send_dbmail with database context by either fully qualifying your table in the `@query` parameter:

```
@query = 'SELECT id FROM testDB.dbo.TestTable'
```

or by providing the optional `@execute_query_database` parameter:

```
@execute_query_database = 'testDB'
```

Answer (score 2):

Enable sysadmin server role for the account that is used to run the SQL Server Agent.Below are the screenshots.

**Error**

[image: Failed to initialize sqlcmd library with error number -2147467259]

**Fix**

[image: Enable server role sysadmin for SQL Server Account running SQL Server Agent]

Now the SQL Server Job runs without any errors and I get an email from dbmail.

[image]

Comment: This was the fix for me.  No combination of `@execute_query_database` or fully qualified table references was solving the issue for me.  In my case the `@query` was a join across two different databases, and even if I put it all in a view, I could not get it to work until I followed this advice and gave the SQL Agent sysadmin rights.

Comment: @N1njaB0b Glad to know it worked for you. Upvote :-) ?

Comment: This turned out to be the problem for me as well...  But I am wondering if there is a lesser set of permissions than 'sysadmin' that would work?

Answer (score 0):

There's another reason why you might get this error; if the query has an issue.

In our case we had (note that it's not due to a syntax error; note the missing quotes):

```
DECLARE @EmailQuery varchar(max) = 'select 
                                    e.Field1,
                                    REPLACE(REPLACE(e.ExceptionReason, CHAR(13), ''), CHAR(10), '') ExceptionReason,
                                    e.UserName
                                from dbo.tblException e'
```

Once we corrected it as follows, it worked fine:

```
DECLARE @EmailQuery varchar(max) = 'select 
                                    e.Field1,
                                    REPLACE(REPLACE(e.ExceptionReason, CHAR(13), ''''), CHAR(10), '''') ExceptionReason,
                                    e.UserName
                                from dbo.tblException e'
```