# Is there a limitation to the complexity of a SQL Query where you are emailing the results?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Please see below. I don't feel its particularly complex but I keep erroring out. Syntax?

Error is "Failed to initialize sqlcmd library with error number -2147467259"

Any suggestions would be appreciated

```
    EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail 
    @profile_name = 'fpmetrics',
    @recipients='Brian@Test.com',
    @query = N'select i.ticket_number, i.status_1 as Status, i.title, 
    i.description,  u.user_login as ''Assignee'', i.created_on from 
    fpscdb008_system.asgnmt a, fpscdb008_system.app_user u, 
    fpscdb008_ws_004.incidents i
    where i.id = a.item_id
    and a.item_defn_id = 12610
    and u.app_user_id = a.app_user_id
    and i.soft_delete_id = 0 
    and i.status_1 not in (''Closed'',''Resolved'',''Cancelled'')
    Union
    select s.ticket_number, s.status_1 as Status, s.title, s.description,  
    u.user_login as ''Assignee'', s.created_on from 
    fpscdb008_system.asgnmt a, fpscdb008_system.app_user u, 
    fpscdb008_ws_004.service_request s
    where a.app_user_id = u.app_user_id
    and a.item_defn_id = 7861
    and s.id = a.item_id
    and s.soft_delete_id = 0 
    and s.status_1 not in (''Closed'',''Resolved'',''Cancelled'');',
    @attach_query_result_as_file = 1,
    @query_attachment_filename = 'Values.csv',
    @query_result_separator=',',
    @subject = 'pie';
```

Comment: Is that query executing successfully? Does sp_send_dbmail  work without query?

Comment: did you enable sp_configure.?

Comment: Yes, if I use a far simpler query, it does work. The query on its own also works.

Comment: Not a fix but you really should get in the habit of using ANSI-92 style joins. They have been around for more than 25 years now. https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins

Comment: You might try google....there seems to be a LOT of examples of this. https://www.google.com/search?q=Failed+to+initialize+sqlcmd+library+with+error+number+-2147467259&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b-1

Comment: Possibly this https://stackoverflow.com/a/29516906/73226

Comment: There are query limits, although I doubt the email utility does anything different than "run" the query normally (the only way it could reasonably enforce its own limits is to have the engine take a look at it, at which point you might as well just have the thing try it anyways).  Normal limits on queries are nowhere near a query this simple, though.  Oh, and the query can potentially be simplified further, since the only difference is `a.item_defn_id`, which could use an `IN` clause...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's likely the problem occured because you didn't use three-names notation:  db_name.schema_name.table_name

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/86a9eeeb-bd60-4cf6-961b-6e686af6f160/failed-to-initialize-sqlcmd-library-with-error-number-2147024809?forum=sqldatabaseengine

Comment: you nailed it.. thank you.. much appreciated.. its doing what its supposed to!